# Calculating an integral, with help of derivative.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral:
$$I(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-y}\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

I need to calculate it with derivative by parameter, for $-1<y<1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-y}=1+\frac{2y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-y}\implies$$

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-y}\right)=\frac{2(\sqrt{1+x^2}-y)+2y}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-y\right)^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-y\right)^2}\implies$$$${}$$

Now, using Leibniz integral theorem for differentiation under the integral sign... *but* this is an improper integral and some additional conditions, besides the usual ones for definite integrals, must be met. I think this is fine this time, but you may want to check this, for example theorem 3.2 page 337, ch. XIII, 3, in Lang's "Undergraduate Analysis":$${}$$

$$I'(y)=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\color{red}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-y\right)^2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+y}\cdot\frac1{\color{red}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}dx=$$

$$=2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1-y^2+x^2}=\frac2{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}}{1+\left(\cfrac x{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)^2}=$$

$$=\left.\frac2{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right|_0^\infty=\frac\pi{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\implies$$$${}$$

$$I(y)=\int\frac\pi{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=\pi\arcsin y+K\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
I(y) = \int_{f_1(y)}^{f_2(y)} g(x,y) dx
\rightarrow
I'(y) =
\frac{\partial f_1(y)}{\partial y}
g(f_1(y),y)
-
\frac{\partial f_2(y)}{\partial y}
g(f_2(y),y)
+
\int_{f_1(y)}^{f_2(y)} \frac{\partial  g(x,y)}{\partial y} dx
\end{equation}
in your case, $g(x,y)$ is the function in the integral, $f_1(y) = 0$, and $f_2(y) = \infty$, so derive it w.r.t $y$ to obtain the third term. Moreover, the first and second terms of the above are $0$ because $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$ are independent of $y$.